# Ggplot, Last Geom_point colouring overwrites the first colouring

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

How can I make the colouring of points specific? As the code shows below which I used the last color overwrites the first colour and now on my legend I have data1 and data2 with the same colour, which is not what I want.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,color,group))+
geom_point(data1,aes(fill="data1"),shape="*",size=12,color="blue")+
geom_point(data2,aes(fill="data2"),shape="*",size=12,color="red")
```

Just to highlight that data1 and data2 where derived by data on certain conditions

Comment: first pivot_longer "data", then use one geom_point command and fill on the group name

Answer (score 1):

First, let's talk about what's really going on in your example.  Then, I'll provide two ways to solve it.

#### What is Really Happening in OP's example

Here's a reprex of OP's example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(8675309)
data1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10, 10))
data2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:10, 10, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(10, 11, 0.4))

ggplot(mapping= aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(fill='data1'), shape='*', size=12, color='blue') +
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(fill='data2'), shape='*', size=12, color='red')
```

[image]

On first glance it *looks* like the points are colored as we wanted them to be, but the legend is colored only by the last `geom_point`.  **But**... that's not actually what's going on here.  In reality, the result in the legend is due to drawing a red point *on top of a blue point* in both legend keys.  We can demonstrate this very clearly when you change the shape of the blue point:

```
ggplot(mapping= aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(fill='data1'), size=12, color='blue') +
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(fill='data2'), shape='*', size=12, color='red')
```

[image]

The reason for the overplotting is simple:  OP has set the `fill` aesthetic in `aes()` and  then adjusted the `color` modifier discretely.  Therefore, the legend does not reflect the difference in `color`, but the difference in `fill`.  Since "*" is not a shape that has a `fill`, there is no difference in appearance other than the difference in `color`.

#### How to Fix

There are two ways to fix this.  Both involve moving `color` from *outside* `aes()` to *inside* `aes()`.  One way maintains the two datasets `data1` and `data2` as separate data frames as OP has it, where we have a `geom_point` call for each dataset, and the second way applies [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) principles and is generally **much better practice** for plotting with `ggplot2`.

**The non-Tidy Way**

Move `color` inside `aes()` for both `geom_point` calls and remove `fill`, since it doesn't apply here.  The result of doing this will mean that `ggplot` will create a legend and add "data1" and "data2" to that legend.  Colors are chosen automatically, but if we want to specify the color, we can use `scale_color_manual()`:

```
ggplot(mapping= aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(color='data1'), shape='*', size=12) +
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(color='data2'), shape='*', size=12) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

By the way, if you keep `color` inside *and* outside `aes()`, the `color` *outside* of `aes()` will overwrite the one inside the `aes()` function.  This means your points will be the right color, but no legend is drawn.

**The Tidy Data Way**

Again, this way is much more preferred.  The idea is that you should combine your datasets into one, adding a column to differentiate the origin of the data.  You then use that column to indicate how to label and color the points.  You only need one call to `geom_point` to make this work.  It may not look so much improved in this particular example, but consider what the difference would be if you had 10 datasets.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# note we add a named list to ensure the id column is correctly populated
df <- bind_rows(list(data1=data1, data2=data2), .id="id")

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=id)) + geom_point(shape='*', size=12) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue', 'red'))
```

The resulting plot is identical to the other one.

### EDIT: What if there already is a color aesthetic?

While not a part of the question, OP indicated that in their particular case, there was already a `color` aesthetic defined (so the values sent for `scale_color_manual()` were not sufficient.  There are some options for how to proceed here:

- In OP's case, the message indicated they needed to provide 6, not 2 values.  OP can try to supply 6 colors and map them accordingly using a named vector (i.e. `c("data1" = "blue", "data2" = "red", ...`).
- Use a point shape that has a fill color and use that for the separate legend
- Use the same asterisk `*` point shape and color, but override the aesthetics in the legend.

Without the actual data from the OP and the code they are using specifically that includes the conflicting color aesthetic, it's difficult to suggest the best course for that particular case; however, I'll demonstrate the final two approaches here:

#### Use point shape with a fill color

```
ggplot(mapping= aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(fill='data1'), shape=21, size=12, color='NA') +
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(fill='data2'), shape=21, size=12, color='NA') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('data1'='blue', 'data2'='red'))
```

[image]

#### Override the aesthetics of the color legend

```
ggplot(mapping= aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(fill='data1'), shape='*', size=12, color='blue') +
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(fill='data2'), shape='*', size=12, color='red') +
  guides(
    fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=c('blue','red')))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: well that doesn't work for me because I have already used the color in aesthetics and group for another reason to colour the  line. When I try    scale_color_manual(values=c('blue', 'red')) it gives me this  Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 2 provided.

Comment: I see - this information was not provided in your initial question.  If you can add an example of your data, you can probably get  solution to that particular issue.... the alternative is to *only* use the fill aesthetic by choosing a point shape that has a fill (and setting the color to NA or black.

Comment: Regardless, I've added your provisions to the answer as an Edit.  One of those approaches should work for your case, but if not, I would ask you post that as a separate question indicated where you have the conflict.